# Using capybara-webkit with HTTPS in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, webkit, capybara-webkit

Does anyone know if it is possible to use capybara-webkit using HTTPS with ruby on rails.

My app runs with HTTPS forced in production. To keep test as similar to production, I also want it to use HTTPS.

I have got rspec request specs using HTTPS with `https!`

However I cannot get rspec features working using capybara-webkit. I have tried a few options similar to the following:

```
Capybara.default_driver = :webkit
Capybara.server_port = 37_511
Capybara.default_host = 'https://localhost'
Capybara.app_host = "#{Capybara.default_host}:#{Capybara.server_port}"

Capybara::Webkit.configure do |config|
  config.raise_javascript_errors = true
  config.ignore_ssl_errors
```

Error:

```
Capybara::Webkit::InvalidResponseError:
   Unable to load URL: https://localhost:37511/home because of error loading https://localhost:37511/home: Unknown error
```

My versions are:

```
ruby 2.3.4
rails 5.0.4
capybara-webkit 1.14.0
capybara 2.13.0
rspec 3.6.0
```